# $_SESSION does not keep values between pages

Tags: php, session, php-7.3

**Observation:**

Sending form data from page_1 and page_2 does not show both data in result file.
If sending page_1 one sees the result in result file. When sending page_2 the result of page_1 is gone and you only see the page_2. It behaves as the content of $_SESSION['data'] is 
overwritten every time one sends either page_1 or page_2.

The session id of all 3 pages are identical.

**Wanted result:**

Every time running result.php one should see the accumulated actions, e.g. if pressing page_1 first time you only see page_1 data, if pressing page_2 you would see both page_1- and page_2- data. When pressing page_1 the second time, the page_1 value should be updated and visible when pressing result.php

**PHP version**

Terminal: PHP 7.4.6

Browser: 7.3.18-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1

**Page_1:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page-1</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="input_1" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Save</button>
</form>

<pre>

<?php

$_SESSION["data"] = $_POST;
print_r($_SESSION);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Page_2:**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Page-2</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post">
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="input_2" value="">
  <button type="submit" name="button">Save</button>
</form>

<pre>

<?php

$_SESSION["data"] = $_POST;
print_r($_SESSION);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Result:**

```
<pre>

<?php
session_start();
echo session_id() . "<br /><br />";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Do not think there is any unclarity in the question. The question is close purely for the narcissistic approach that the SO has. We that are not same experts as you obviously are need to be able to ask questions without having the questions closed.

Comment: You're welcome to provide more information and vote to re-open this question. But can you answer what you **expect** from this code to happen, and how you tried to validate which parts worked, and which don't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you send form you overwrite $_SESSION

You should use either

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $_SESSION["data"]['page1'] = $_POST; //and analogically for page2
}
```

OR

```
$_SESSION["data"] = array_merge($_SESSION["data"],$_POST);
```

Answer (score 2):

> It behaves as the content of $_SESSION['data'] is overwritten every time one sends either page_1 or page_2.

Because this is exactly what you're doing. The line `$_SESSION["data"] = $_POST;` appears in both page_1 and page_2, and there's nothing that preserves the old value of `$_SESSION["data"]` before new data is written.

If you want to add the data instead of replacing it, you could write, for example, `$_SESSION["data"][] = $_POST;` in both pages. This will create an array in `$_SESSION["data"]` and append `$_POST` data to it each time you open either page.